# Do the cryptic symbols/letters throughout the Bizenghast series mean anything?

Tags: bizenghast

In the Bizenghast manga series, the author uses some symbols over and over again to represent writing or add to the style of the panels:
[image: A letter on a desk written in symbols]
[image: An open book containing similar symbols]
[image]

There are other parts of the book that just represent writing as scribbles or lines, so I wasn't sure if the symbols meant anything because they seem like intentional words or writing.

**Do the symbols mean anything? Or are they just meant so that they don't have to be translated if the book were translated to other languages for other readers?**

If this is just a font or based on a font (like windgings or webdings), **does anyone know what font it is?** The symbols don't seem to be random and they could appear to spell words.

Comment: Note that the author is an English speaker, and she mentioned her contact on [its Wikipedia's Talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Bizenghast#%22I_did_it_for_the_lulz%22) (deliberately not mentioned on the comment due to potential privacy issue). Maybe someone can contact here to get the official answer, or maybe even ask her to post the answer directly on here?